# Detection only shows 1 class, but trained 70

Tags: image, yolo, darknet

I trained a neuronal net via yolov3 for 70 classes. Unfortunately when I try to detect the classes, only one class per image is shown.

I tried to show me all the classes by setting the threshold to 0 and it did show me more classes, but not the ones I trained for.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error and it was somewhere else. I used a labeling-tool to label my images and after I have labeled everything, decided to go for one more object to label. So I have labeled everything again and by that, my tool overwrote the .txt-files (containing only one class). But in the images my tool has presented to me, every label was still set for some unknown reason. So I have relabeled again everything and now it should work (still in training right now but first test was ok).